# Jira On Demand, get the email id of the actual sender

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

We are on JIRA On Demand. We have one Email handler configured to create/update tickets if we receive emails on a particular email id. In most of the cases, the emails will be from outside email ids and hence we have a JIRA user id by which the emails from unknown ids will be created as issues. So reporter of the issue will be our JIRA user though the emails are from some unknown email ids. Is there any way to get the actual "FROM Email ids" and put it in a custom field or at least to get the correct email id.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Atlassian page on [creating isses from incoming emails](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/creating-issues-and-comments-from-email-185729464.html) the "From" is appended at the end of the message body if you are using Default Reporter:

> Default Reporter
>
> Specify the username of a default reporter, which will be used if the email address in the From: field of any received messages does not match the address associated with that of an existing JIRA user — for example, a JIRA username such as emailed-reporter
>
> (info) Note:
>
> When an issue is created and this option is specified, the email message's From: field address is appended in a brief message at the end of the issue's Description field, so that the sender can be identified.

Unfortunately there doesn't look like a convenient way to transfer this to an issue field. At least the information will be present though in the issue description.

Comment: Thanks. I got it done via REST api. In the issue details we will get the from email id like this "Created via e-mail received from: someone@theirdomain.com". Then using REST api only updating this to the custom field.

Comment: That's a neat solution!